# rule engine function inside Meteor bindEnvironment losing its this object

Tags: javascript, meteor, rule-engine

```
var process_request_rule = [
  {
    "name": "rule-name",
    "condition": Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (R) {
      R.when(this.request.type == 'some-type');
    })
  }];
```

In the above code, **this.request** was getting undefined as **this** was pointing to Meteor object not to the function object. After researching got to know  that using arrow functions might resolve the issue. Tried using that as shown below.

```
var process_request_rule = [
  {
    "name": "rule-name",
    "condition": Meteor.bindEnvironment((R) => {
      R.when(this.request.type == 'some-type');
     })
  }];
```

Still no luck, Please help me binding **this** object

Comment: What are you expecting to be in function's `this` if you're using `Meteor.bindEnvironment`?

Comment: `this` refers to the fact of the rule that is currently executing.
PS: using npm node-rules in Meteor application
reference for node-rules: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either drop using `Meteor.bindEnvironment` or just use second argument passed to `condition` callback — it is the same as supposed `this`. https://github.com/mithunsatheesh/node-rules/blob/master/lib/node-rules.js#L94

Something like this:

```
var process_request_rule = [
  {
    "name": "rule-name",
    "condition": Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(R, session) {
      R.when(session.request.type == 'some-type');
     })
  }];
```

Comment: I cannot drop using `Meteor.bindEnvironment` as I need to have callbacks inside Meteor, else I will error saying `can't wait without a fiber`.
and what is session here ?

Comment: The same object that would be bound as `this` to this condition function. You can rename it as `self` or `_this` to avoid confusing :)